# Question on Javascript Exercise in Head First JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my first stackoverflow post! I am sorry if I botch the protocol on how to post. Let me know if I have :-)

I am working through this exercise in Head First Javascript and I don't know why an alternative won't work.

We iterate through passengers in order to find the type of ticket. Depending on the ticket we will provide a different alert: firstclass or else.

In this exercise, at function createDrinkOrders , we are calling a function (orderFunction) in order to provide alert.

Why does this not work if I DO NOT use the orderFunctions in createDrinkOrders?

I removed the orderFunctions in createDrinkOrders, but it alerts two or three times. If I include the orderFunctions in createDrinkOrders, it alerts 12 times. Why do we need the orderFunctions function here?

I imagine that after the iteration the alert, with or without the orderFunction, would produce the same result, but it doesn't why?

```js
let passengers = [{
    name: "Jane Doloop",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Evael",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "Sue Propert",
    paid: false,
    ticket: "firstclass"
  },
  {
    name: "John Funcall",
    paid: true,
    ticket: "coach"
  }
];

function createDrinkOrders(passenger) {
  let orderFunction;
  if (passenger.ticket === "firstclass") {
    orderFunction = function() {
      alert("Would you like a cocktail or wine?")
    }
  } else {
    orderFunction = function() {
      alert("Your choice is cola or nothing!")
    };
  }
  return orderFunction;
};



function serveCustomer(passenger) {
  let getDrinkOrderFunction = createDrinkOrders(passenger);
  getDrinkOrderfunction();
  getDrinkOrderFunction();
  getDrinkOrderFunction();
  getDrinkOrderFunction();



};

function servePassengers(passengers) {
  for (let i = 0; passengers.length; i++) {
    serveCustomer(passengers[i]);
  }
};

servePassengers(passengers);
```

Now the code without the orderFunction... See createDrinkOrders(passengers).

```
let passengers =[{name: "Jane Doloop", paid: true, ticket: "coach"},
                 {name: "Dr. Evael", paid: true, ticket: "firstclass"},
                 {name: "Sue Propert", paid: false, ticket: "firstclass"},
                 {name: "John Funcall", paid: true, ticket:"coach"}];

    function createDrinkOrders(passenger){

        if(passenger.ticket === "firstclass"){

            alert("Would you like a cocktail or wine?")

        }else{

            alert("Your choice is cola or nothing!")

        }

    };



    function serveCustomer (passenger){


       getDrinkOrderfunction();
       getDrinkOrderfunction();

       getDrinkOrderfunction();

       getDrinkOrderfunction();



    };

    function servePassengers (passengers){
        for(let i = 0; passengers.length; i++){
            serveCustomer(passengers[i]);
        }
    };

    servePassengers(passengers);
```

Comment: That depends wholly on how you 'removed' the order functions.  Please provide a sample of that removal, just like you did with the code before it was modified.

Comment: Hello! I updated the original code. I tested it. It has 16 alerts. Now, without the orderFunction:

Comment: I edited it, and put in a new piece of code. Thanks for being patient, I just signed up for stackoverflow and I am still learning the interface. :-)

Comment: The second example will produce an error because `getDrinkOrderfunction` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Daedalus can you explain a bit, you said it is simple. If I use orderFunction or don't use orderFunction, is the result the same? Is using orderFunction just extra code, or is it necessary?

Comment: @Titus OK cool. Let me edit that out. But I am still confused on the NEED for orderFunction when we have an iterator.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do, it makes things easier to have it if you're planning to show the same alert multiple times for the same user, if not, you don't need to use it.

Comment: Yes, the exercise is to show the same alert for the same user. I do not understand why orderFunction helps us do that. Wouldn't the iterator just iterate over each passenger 4X (due to the serveCustomer calling getDrinkOrderFunction 4X)? I do understand why that does not have the same effect as using orderFunction.

Comment: In the first example you're not checking the condition `if(passenger.ticket === "firstclass").....` multiple times, you're just executing the returned function. It seems more efficient (I'm not sure if it is).

Comment: I think I understand it all now. Thanks guy for your help! First stack overflow post was a success!

Answer (score 2):

In your second example you are calling `createDrinkOrders`

```
let getDrinkOrderfunction = createDrinkOrders(passenger);
```

and then try to use its return value by assigning it to `getDrinkOrderfunction`.
Have a look at the implementation of `createDrinkOrders` and you will see that it actually does not return anything. Therefore `getDrinkOrderfunction` is the value `undefined`.

The first following call of `getDrinkOrderfunction()` will fail with an error being thrown.

The original code of `createDrinkOrders` does not actually execute an `alert` - instead it returns a proper function to the caller (which function depends on the parameter).
If the variable `getDrinkOrderfunction` contains a function, it can be executed as many times as you want by writing `getDrinkOrderfunction()`. This will start the actual `alert` notifications.

Let me explain the last paragraph in more detail by simplifying the code:
Let's look at the following alternative implementation of `createDrinkOrders`:

```
function createDrinkOrders() {
    let myFunction = function() {
        alert("Hello World");
    };
    return myFunction;
};
```

What does calling `createDrinkOrders();` actually do?

1. A function is created on the right hand side of the first line; its declaration is split onto multiple lines
2. That function is assigned to the variable `myFunction` of the left hand side of the first line
3. The value of `myFunction` is returned to the caller; that value is the actual function!

Notice that there is no execution of the inner function which got created during the execution of `createDrinkOrders()`.

How to see that?
A function gets executed if you append `()` after an expression yielding a function.
When creating/declaring some value we always my use it immediately or store it in a variable.
Just as you may use numbers in variables by just writing `a+b` you may call a function in a variable `myFunction` by writing `myFunction()`.

Hopefully we understand now that `createDrinkOrders()` yields a value which turns out to be a function.

If we write

```
let foobar = createDrinkOrders();
```

we now have that value in the variable `foobar` and it is ready to be called.

```
foobar(); // call the function stored in foobar
foobar(); // calls it again
```

Comment: So, I removed let getDrinkOrderfunction = createDrinkOrders(passenger).  I see that createDrinkOrders does not create an alert. Can you explain your last paragraph a bit more, its blowing my mind a bit and I can see that the answer to my question is there.

Comment: I've added further explanations to my answer.

Comment: @HeroWanders in your second code snippet `return orderFunction;` should be `return myFunction;`

Comment: I think I got !  I made a mental mistake. createDrinkOrderFunction does not iterate at all! It simply packages two functions comfortably based on a condtion (if firstclass or else). Function serve customer handles this and calls it 4 times. The results of the 4 times is dependent upon the function servePassengers--which does the iterating! I hope I got this right :-) Also, how in the hell do you create paragraphs in stackoverflow!?! I hit enter and it submits :-)

Comment: @HeroWanders Thanks for that extra detail in your answer! Great help, especially the return part. That clears things up for me a bit!

Comment: @HeroWanders, Can you guys check my understanding in my above comment. I feel that I wrapped my head around this problem, but I want to make sure.

Comment: @Vincent, right: servePassengers iterates the passengers and delegates further work for each one to serveCustomer. serveCustomer lets createDrinkOrders decide how to ask the customer and then raises that question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
function a() {
    let b = c(); //calling c() returns a function that can be called later

    b(); //alert('q') runs here
    b(); //alert('q') runs again here
}

function c() {
    return function() {
        alert('q');
    };
}
```

Option 2:

```
function a() {
    let b = c(); //alert('q') runs here

    b(); //throws an error here because b is not defined
    b(); //throws an error here because b is not defined
}

function c() {
    alert('q');
}
```